# set state in onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, setstate

I have 2 submit buttons in my react form.

I am trying to use an `onClick` function to get the `id` of the clicked button, so I can then specify how to handle each accordingly.

My `onClick` function is returning undefined for the `setState` of the `id`.

**How can I properly grab the `id` of the button and set the state?**

```
handleClick() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonsCount; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = (e) => {
            this.setState({clickedSubmit: this.id});
            console.log(this.state.clickedSubmit); //returns undefined
        };
    }
}

//in the render
<button id="formSubmit" className="btn btn-info" name="submitButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
<button id="hashSubmit" className="btn btn-info" name="submitButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>Generate Hash</button>
```

Comment: You can access the value with `this.props.id`

Comment: ^ actually, to use `this.props.id` you would have to create a component for the buttons, which might be more than you desire to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find your element id in the event of the onClick handler that is `e.target.id`

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  this.setState({ clickedSubmit: e.target.id },() => {
    console.log(this.state.clickedSubmit)
  });
}

//in the render
<button id="formSubmit" className="btn btn-info" name="submitButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
<button id="hashSubmit" className="btn btn-info" name="submitButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>Generate Hash</button>
```

Comment: Short, simple, and does just what I need. Using e.target.id worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend changing how you invoke handleClick slightly, by passing in an argument for buttonId.

In your render function:

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick('formSubmit')}>Submit</button>
```

In handleClick:

```
handleClick(buttonId) { ... }
```

As I posted in my comment, you have an option to separate the button out into it's own component. In that case, you would be able to use simple like `this.props.id` to get the value of id.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for a simpler approach, something like this

```
handleClick1() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
    let id = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonsCount; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = (e) => {
            this.setState({clickedSubmit: id});
            console.log(this.state.clickedSubmit); //returns undefined
       };
  }
}

handleClick2() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
    let id = 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonsCount; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = (e) => {
            this.setState({clickedSubmit: id});
            console.log(this.state.clickedSubmit); //returns undefined
       };
  }
}

//in the render
    <button id="formSubmit" className="btn btn-info" name="submitButton" onClick={this.handleClick1}>Submit</button>
    <button id="hashSubmit" className="btn btn-info" name="submitButton" onClick={this.handleClick2}>Generate Hash</button>
```

The benefit of this approach is, in future when your button count increases, then at that time, your code should be modular so that it is easy to add new functionality to your app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is supposed to be good? You duplicate a function, which uses slow Web API calls to read state, and the only thing dynamic between the 2 functions is the id, which you could pass as an arg to onClick directly, ex: `onClick={() => this.handleClick('formSubmit')}`

Comment: I meant good because obviously for the testing purpose, he is setting state but the name suggests one is for form submitting and another for hash submit or calculating hash, so having two different methods could make it easier for handling all that stuff rather than placing a nested case of if's inside one method

Answer (score 0):

You can get `id` of your buttons by using `event.target`, like below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clickedId: -1,
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const id = event.target.id;
    this.setState({
      clickedId: id,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Clicked id: {this.state.clickedId}</h1>
        <button id="asd" onClick={this.handleClick}>Asd</button>
        <button id="qwe" onClick={this.handleClick}>Qwe</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yiqavav/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, even change id to other parameter you want to pass in to the your function.

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.handlefunction(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
<button onClick={this.handlefunction.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
```

This article helps a great deal:

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html